# MySQL brake comma list into columns

Tags: mysql

I need to brake hashtags comma list into separate columns.

```
| hashtag  |
------------
| us       |
| jk,test  |
|          |
| us,we,jk |
```

The query is fine its just need to be able to look at the tags in comma lists too? Any improvements would be ok.

[TEST HERE!](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58b11d/2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substring_index()`.  For the example in your question:

```
select substring_index(hashtag, ',', 1) as tag1,
       (case when hashtag like '%,%'
             then substring_index(substring_index(hashtag, ',', 2), ',', -1)
        end) as tag2,
       (case when hashtag like '%,%,%'
             then substring_index(hashtag, ',', -1)
        end) as tag3
. . .
```